# How can I center text in a div with viewport units?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport

When using pixel units, I can align text no problem. But with viewport units, I can't get anywhere. Here is my code.

```css
#aboutMeTitle {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: #BEA69B;
  display: block;
}
#aboutMeTitle p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "FontAwesome Regular";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="aboutMeTitle">
  <p>About Me</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `display: inline-block;` on the paragraph may *not* be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple with CSS flexbox:

```css
#aboutMeTitle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;  /* center p horizontally */
  align-items: center;      /* center p vertically */
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: #BEA69B;
}
#aboutMeTitle p {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="aboutMeTitle">
  <p>About Me</p>
 </div>
```

***Browser support:*** *Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE < 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).*

Comment: That works also. I had applied a 'line-height:10vh' and that did the trick but the flex box also did the same thing. I just wonder which technique is more widely supported?

Comment: You're already using viewport percentage units. So you can safely use flexbox. Both are cutting-edge, CSS3 technologies. In terms of which is more widely supported, that would be flexbox (see caniuse.com).

Answer (score 0):

For vertical-align:middle to work the parent must be set to display:table-cell
HTML

```
<div class="row" id="aboutMeTitle"><p>About Me</p></div>
```

CSS

```
#aboutMeTitle {
height: 10vh;
background-color: #BEA69B;
display:block;
display:table-cell;
}

#aboutMeTitle p {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "FontAwesome Regular";
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 0.2em;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: That fixed the text-align property back to normal so it is horizontally centered. However I cannot get it vertically centered. Normally I just put the line height to the same value as the div but you cannot set line height to a viewport unit; or if you can I don't know a trick to do so. any insight?

Comment: I apologize, I worded the title wrong. My main problem was the vertical alignment, not the horizontal alignment of the text.

Answer (score 0):

You just removed `display: inline-block` in `#aboutMeTitle p`, and adding `line-height: 10vh;` to make text center in vertical.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="row" id="aboutMeTitle"><p>About Me</p></div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#aboutMeTitle {
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: #BEA69B;
    display: block;
}
#aboutMeTitle p {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "FontAwesome Regular";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height: 10vh;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ge0a61Le/)

Answer (score 0):

I feel really stupid and I apologize for bothering anyone with this. Hopefully this answer can help someone else though. I worked a double on 4 hours of sleep and now i'm working on a personal project. Anyway,you can apply a line-height property with viewport units, i just had to hard code it instead, because its not an option in the DW CSS panel.

Here is the fixed CSS

```
#aboutMeTitle {
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: #BEA69B;
    display: block;
}
#aboutMeTitle p {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "FontAwesome Regular";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 10vh;
}
```